# Gráficos estadísticos en tiempo real aspnet

Tags: c#, asp.net, real-time

Me pueden ayudar trato de mostrar un gráfico estadístico en aspnet con datos consumidos de una base de datos el cual se vaya refrescando según vayan agregándose datos a la misma

Comment: Hola Ricardo, por favor edita tu pregunta siguiendo está guía: [mcve]. Es importante que muestres un ejemplo claro y verificable __de lo qué estás haciendo para resolver tu problema__.

Answer (score 1):

Para actualizar un grafico en tiempo real con datos generados desde el servidor deberias evaluar implementar `SignalR`

[Hands On Lab: Real-Time Web Applications with SignalR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/real-time-web-applications-with-signalr)

Con esta tecnologia podras aplicar lo que se conoce como `Server Push`, o sea podras enviar datos al cliente si que este tenga que realizar un request al servidor.

[Real Time Chart Using SignalR and Chart.js](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jj12345678910/real-time-chart-using-signalr-and-chart-js/)

[Real Time Chart With SignalR and ASP.NET MVC](http://techbrij.com/jquery-flot-signalr-asp-net-mvc-chart)

El chart que uses para representar la grafica no afecta siempre que sea basado en javascript/jquery y el origen de datos sea json